Cannot write \Cup in tikz-qtree binary tree structure in LateX
I stumbled upon this problem while trying to create a LateX binary tree in my Overleaf project. Through online tutorials, I found out how to construct said binary tree through the tikz-qtree package but faced a problem trying to write the set union operator or \Cup inside the binary tree. Here is my current binary tree code:
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

...

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.c\cup d
    [.c ]
    [.d ]
] 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

The rendered parnet node with the \Cup overflows with a statement like ;edgefromparent;edgefromparent
Which ends up rendering something like this:

I tried to change the font size and use alternative set operators but failed.

Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

symbol \cup should be in math environment. Try [.$c\cup d$     [.c ]     [.d ] ] 

never ignore errror messages. If you get any error don't even look at the generated pdf output, ask about the error message.

If your nodes contain math formulas, you have to tell it to TeX.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[. $c\cup d$
    [. $c$ ]
    [. $d$ ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[. $c\Cup d$
    [. $c$ ]
    [. $d$ ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


I'd check forest, though, instead of tikz-qtree.

Here's a forest version which sets up a style my tree and makes it the default for all forest trees. (This could be shortened a bit by using the linguistics library.)
I don't know whether you want \cup (as your code suggests) or \Cup (as your comments suggest).

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\forestset{%
  my tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      % tell forest nodes should default to maths mode
      math content,
      % ensure edges start from a common point
      parent anchor=children,
      child anchor=parent,
      % make all nodes the same height so the ends of edges align
      delay={content+=\strut},
    },
  },
  % use the above style by default for forest trees
  default preamble={my tree},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [c \cup d [c][d]]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [c \Cup d [c][d]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

Note that no dot is used in forest, so the syntax is slightly different from both qtree and tikz-qtree. (I find it much easier.)

Definitely better output!

@egreg But a steeper learning curve, I guess. (I've never used tikz-qtree, though I used to use a hacked version of qtree.)
